# How to find first non-null record for every column and group by id

Tags: t-sql, sequence

I have a table storing events and I want to create a view of the latest/current state for each id.
Each row in the table should be build up by non-null records with the highest corresponding sequence number.
The Sequence number is carried by the event.
My SQL skills are a bit rusty since i mostly have been working with Cassandra.

I spend a whole day figuring out how to do it and tried a bunch of stuff e.g. using `COALESCE`, `FIRST_VALUE` and different sub SELECT queries. So I think my failed solutions would only confuse if posted here.

Here is the table containing events:

```
|----|------|------|----------|
| Id | A    | B    | Sequence |
|----|------|------|----------|
| 1  | a0   | b0   | 0        |
|----|------|------|----------|
| 2  | a0   | b6   | 0        |
|----|------|------|----------|
| 1  | a1   | NULL | 1        |
|----|------|------|----------|
| 2  | a1   | NULL | 1        |
|----|------|------|----------|
| 2  | NULL | b2   | 2        |
|----|------|------|----------|
| 2  | a3   | b3   | 3        |
|----|------|------|----------|
| 2  | NULL | b4   | 4        |
|----|------|------|----------|
```

... and the view a want to achieve:

```
|----|----|----|----------|
| Id | A  | B  | Sequence |
|----|----|----|----------|
| 1  | a1 | b0 | 1        |
|----|----|----|----------|
| 2  | a3 | b4 | 4        |
|----|----|----|----------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to use good old fashion subqueries.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Id int,
    A char(2),
    B char(2),
    Sequence int
)

INSERT INTO @T (Id, A, B, Sequence) VALUES
(1, 'a0', 'b0', 0),
(2, 'a0', 'b6', 0),
(1, 'a1', NULL, 1),
(2, 'a1', NULL, 1),
(2, NULL, 'b2', 2),
(2, 'a3', 'b3', 3),
(2, NULL, 'b4', 4);
```

The query:

```
SELECT  Id, 
        (
            -- get the last non-null A value for the specified Id
            SELECT TOP 1 A 
            FROM @T As T1
            WHERE T1.Id = T0.Id
            AND A IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY Sequence DESC
        ) As A,
        (
            -- get the last non-null B value for the specified Id
            SELECT TOP 1 B 
            FROM @T As T1
            WHERE T1.Id = T0.Id
            AND B IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY Sequence DESC
        ) As B,
        MAX(Sequence) As Sequence
FROM @T As T0
GROUP BY Id
```

Result:

```
Id  A   B   Sequence
1   a1  b0  1
2   a3  b4  4
```

Comment: Thanks man! I guess we posted at the same time :) I will give you the credit. I will remember to create and populate a sample table in the future.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you keep pushing results will come :-) I managed to figure it out. For anyone interested, here is the code:

```
SELECT [id],
       [A] = (
           SELECT TOP (1) [A]
           FROM [dbo].[Table]
           WHERE [A] IS NOT NULL
               AND [Current].[Id] = [Id]
           ORDER BY [Sequence] DESC
       ),
       [B] = (
           SELECT TOP (1) [B]
           FROM [dbo].[Table]
           WHERE [B] IS NOT NULL
               AND [Current].[Id] = [Id]
           ORDER BY [Sequence] DESC
       ),
       [HighestSequence] = (
           SELECT TOP (1) [Sequence]
           FROM [dbo].[Table]
           WHERE [Current].[Id] = [Id]
           ORDER BY [Sequence] DESC
       )
FROM (SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Table]) AS [Current]
GROUP BY [Id]
```

I am unaware of how the query will perform, but in my scenario it will be suitable.
Please let me know if you discover any flaws. Improvements are always welcoming.